# Spring JPA Column not create but call works

Tags: database, spring, jpa

im using spring boot jpa .
i tried to create an update call + method that will create a storge income when its called but for some reason its not creating it .

on the other hand when i try to call for create method its creating the line in data base.

here is some code :

the first 1 working fine creating the line in the table.

```
public Coupon createCoupon(Coupon coupon, int companyId) throws Exception {
        if (checkIfTitleAlreadyExists(coupon.getTitle()) == false) {
            coupon.setCompany(companyRepo.findById(companyId));
            if (checkIfCompanyExists(companyId)) {
                LocalDate couponCreatingDate = LocalDate.now();
                Date couponDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(couponCreatingDate);
                coupon.setStartDate(couponDate);
                couponRepo.save(coupon);

                Income income = new Income();
                income.setClientId(companyId);
                income.setPrice(100.0);
                income.setDescription(IncomeType.COMPANY_NEW_COUPON);
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
                Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
                income.setDate(date);
                income.setName(coupon.getCompany().getComp_Name());
                incomeRepo.save(income);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("This Company is not exists");
            }

        } else {
            throw new Exception("The title " + coupon.getTitle() + " already exist, please try another title");
        }
        return coupon;
    }
```

the second 1 not create the line in table :

```
public Coupon updateCoupon(int companyid,Coupon coupon) {
        Coupon currentCoupon = couponRepo.findById(coupon.getid());
        currentCoupon.setEndDate(coupon.getEndDate());
        currentCoupon.setPrice(coupon.getPrice());
        couponRepo.saveAndFlush(currentCoupon);

        Income income = new Income();
        income.setClientId(companyid);
        income.setPrice(10.0);
        income.setDescription(IncomeType.COMPANY_UPDATE_COUPON);
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
        income.setDate(date);
        income.setName(coupon.getCompany().getComp_Name());
        incomeRepo.save(income);

        return currentCoupon;

    }
```

the 2 http calls:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/coupon/{companyid}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCoupon(@RequestBody Coupon coupon, HttpServletRequest req) {
        try {
            companyService.createCoupon(coupon, getLoggedUser(req).getUserId());
            return new ResponseEntity<>("coupon created", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage() + e.getStackTrace(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

    }

    @PutMapping("/coupon/{companyid}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCoupon(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestBody Coupon coupon) {
        try {
            companyService.updateCoupon(getLoggedUser(req).getUserId(), coupon);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    }
```

ty for the helpers .

Comment: Have you tried adding `e.printStackTrace()` or even better logging the exception with SLF4J or something?

Comment: You need to post you `entity` and repository classes, please do check out @CreationTimestamp and replace that hideous way you are setting the creation date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `updateCoupon` logic seems to be wrong. If update is success you are returning Error and if any exception returning success. huh?

Also in `createCoupon` I can see that you are setting company after querying it

```
coupon.setCompany(companyRepo.findById(companyId));
```

Same piece of code is missing in `updateCoupon`

Try below code

```
@PutMapping("/coupon/{companyid}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateCoupon(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestBody Coupon coupon) {
    try {
        companyService.updateCoupon(getLoggedUser(req).getUserId(), coupon);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}



public Coupon updateCoupon(int companyid,Coupon coupon) {

    // Maybe Company detail is missing
    coupon.setCompany(companyRepo.findById(companId));

    Coupon currentCoupon = couponRepo.findById(coupon.getid());
    currentCoupon.setEndDate(coupon.getEndDate());
    currentCoupon.setPrice(coupon.getPrice());
    couponRepo.saveAndFlush(currentCoupon);
    Income income = new Income();
    income.setClientId(companyid);
    income.setPrice(10.0);
    income.setDescription(IncomeType.COMPANY_UPDATE_COUPON);
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
    income.setDate(date);
    income.setName(coupon.getCompany().getComp_Name());
    incomeRepo.save(income);
    return currentCoupon;
}
```

If error occur please share log trace from server log.

Comment: btw i try to pull an income info by client id any way u suggestme to do that?

Comment: Glad it worked.  Please accept the answer might help others. Also if I understood it right you can query findByClientId if you are using JPA Repository else can post a new question.

Comment: i did accept it , and you are right im using jpa but the client id created in the income table are same number for  example company id 1 and customer id 1 becouse the id defined by the logged user. so how i can make a chooise between same id?

Comment: i dident break the logic eyt how its work so i can use your help please

Comment: i posted an new post here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488619/spring-jpa-choose-by-logged-user-and-his-id