# Spring Jpa Choose By Logged User and his Id

Tags: spring, jpa

i tried to send an list of income that created by the spacific user that have id , i got company for example and customer , in the table income they both have the same clinet id becouse they id defined by the user id so how i pull the right id becouse if i will try to send get id 1 for example it will pull me all the 1's in the table . ty

some code that i build for now that probably not right :

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public List<Income> viewIncomeByCompany(int clientid) throws Exception {
        LoginUser loginUser = new LoginUser();
        if (loginUser.getClientType().COMPANY != null) {
            List<Income> allIncomesByCompany = incomeRepo.findAllByClientId(clientid);
            return allIncomesByCompany;
        } else {

            throw new Exception();
        }

    }
```

in the Company Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/allincomecompany/{companyid}")
    public List<Income> viewIncomeByCompanyId(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
        List<Income> allcompanyincome = incomeService.viewIncomeByCompany(getLoggedUser(req).getUserId());
        return allcompanyincome;

    }
```

the income table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "income")
public class Income {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "incomeId")
    private int id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long clientId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
//  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date date;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private IncomeType description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private double price;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

income repos:

```
@Repository
public interface IncomeRepo extends JpaRepository<Income, Long> {

    List<Income> findAllByClientId(int clientid);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

Try:

`findByClientId(Long clientId)`

or:

`List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);`

b)

You are using

`int clientid`

where it is:

`long`

Comment: 1 problem its give me all everything that is by that id
 `[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "clientId": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "date": "25-12-2019",
        "description": "COMPANY_NEW_COUPON",
        "price": 100.0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "clientId": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "date": "25-12-2019",
        "description": "CUSTOMER_PURCHASE",
        "price": 4.0
    }
]`

Comment: i think i need to make a switch case but im not sure how to build the logic behind it

Comment: "problem its give me all everything that is by that id" -- all rows with searched `clientId`  is this not what you want? Explain.

Comment: that what i wanted but i need to return income information for by the client that connected to the session i dont want customer to see company income

Comment: `findByClientIdAndCompanyType(Long clientId, YOURS_ENUM_TYPE companyType))` -you can also use `@Query` which will simplifie this method signature to one arg,  but better solution will be to change logic

Comment: i got the logged user defined allready by getLoggedUser(req).getUserId() its defined it as company user becouse im using this

`public LoginUser getLoggedUser(HttpServletRequest req) {
  System.out.println("inside company controller" + req.getSession().getAttribute("user"));
  return (LoginUser) req.getSession(false).getAttribute("user");

 }`

at the company controller but its registar as normal id in income table how i can make this relation between them ?

Comment: im not using any join table at income table no relation between income and company only by id but the id defined as normal number id and not relation value

Comment: this is the final part of my project and i finish it but i cant find a way to over it cant think of a logic around it